# How can i use limit(), valueMap() in gremlin orientdb api?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, orientdb2.2

Ive mounted an orient db distributed instance. I launched the gremlin console, opened the graph.

Even though i can retrieve vertexes by index, i cannot do either the following.

```
g.V().has('@class','user').limit(10)
g.V().has('@class','user').valueMap()
g.V().has('@class','user').select('user_name')
```

and i get the following errors

```
No signature of method: 
com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline.limit() is 
applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [10]
Possible solutions: wait(), min(), last(), first(), 
getAt(java.lang.Integer), wait(long)

No signature of method: 
com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline.valueMap() is 
applicable for argument types: () values: []

No signature of method: 
com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline.select() is 
applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [user_name]
Possible solutions: select(), 
select([Lcom.tinkerpop.pipes.PipeFunction;), 
select([Lgroovy.lang.Closure;), select(java.util.Collection), 
select(java.util.Collection, [Lcom.tinkerpop.pipes.PipeFunction;), 
select(java.util.Collection, [Lgroovy.lang.Closure;)
```

Comment: Hi, which version of orientdb are you using?

Comment: hi. i am using 2.2.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing versions. The syntax of your Gremlin is TinkerPop 3.x but you clearly aren't using a version of the OrientDB TinkerPop implementation that supports that. If you want to use that syntax then you need to use:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin